# Angular Reactive triggering UI operations with rx Signal Store

Tags: angular, rxjs, dialog, signals, reactive

I want to achieve reactively triggering changes in the UI, such as displaying dialogs (even on top of other dialogs)

I am getting closer to use Signal Store, it's working fine.
I have an effect(){} on my AppComponent which handles an boolean "openManagement", this opens a dialog displaying a Mat table with a list, with editing capabilities.
I have my click event which calls the store's appropriate method.
Next step would be to display another dialog on top of the management list, my idea was to create a dialogConfig object in the store, which can be got inside the effect.
Problem is, that I should handle this in the one and only effect section on the AppComponent (another effect section is not allowed within a reactive context)
What I want, is the same as some kind of "action", but it seems to be bloated if I start to handle lots of booleans in my effect on the AppComponent.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.store.isManagementOpen()) {         // this is working fine
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        var dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManagementComponent, dialogConfig);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          this.store.closeManagement();
        });
      }

      const editDialogConfig = this.store.dialogConfig();
      if (editDialogConfig.blabla) {  // I would handle the changes made in the store, to trigger action
            /// open edit dialog
      }

    }
  }
```

I don't like this approach, handling if statements and so on.
I started to think about a kinda "action signal", which would transport the necessary action (eg. EditTask) with the payload. Just like as in the case of ngRx stores.
What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

SignalStore code:

```
export const EntityStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState(initialState),  
  withMethods((store, entityService = inject(EntityService)) => ({
    openManagement() {
      patchState(store, { isManagementOpen: true });
      this.loadAllEntities();
    },
    closeManagement() {
      patchState(store, { isManagementOpen: false })
    },
    openCreateEntityDialog() {
      patchState(store, { entityDialogConfig: {} });
    },
    openEditEntityDialog(entity: Entity) {
      patchState(store, { entityDialogConfig: { entity: entity } });
    },
    loadAllEntities() {
      patchState(store, { loading: true });
      entityService.getEntities()
      .subscribe(
        (entities) =>  { 
          patchState(store, { entities, loading: false })
        }
    );
```

Comment: Are you sure that code Is working? The dialogConfig constant is out of scope to the last if statement.

Comment: Ah thanks Andrea, I just wanted to sketch the workflow with some pseudo code. You were right, I've fixed the code. In the second if statement I want to check if any action was triggered regarding the editDialog

Comment: If you are using SignalStore, you need withMethods() and rxMethod(). See examples in docs. Avoid using `effect()`, and if you have to use it, do not put so much code inside.

Comment: @OZ_ : I use withMethods for sure. I added my store code. Currently I set the bound flags to open the dialogs from there. I detect inside the effect block and execute opening the dialogs. Do you think I should place all dialoghandling code into the store from the effect block? It seems to be a bit strange, having UI logic inside the store.
What do you think?